# Strict aliasing rules broken with templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc, strict-aliasing

The following code gives me warning in gcc that I break strict aliasing rules:

```
struct Base {
  int field = 2;
};

template <typename T>
struct Specialization: public Base {
  void method() {
      Specialization copy;
      field = copy.field;
  }
};

int main() {
    Specialization<int> s;
    s.method();
}
```

> warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will >break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
>          field = copy.field;

When I remove the template, is seems to compile just fine.

```
struct Base {
  int field = 2;
};

struct Specialization: public Base {
  void method() {
      Specialization copy;
      field = copy.field;
  }
};

int main(){
    Specialization s;
    s.method();
}
```

Am I really breaking strict aliasing rules or is it GCC producing a false positive?

I'm using `-Wstrict-aliasing=3 -O3` on GCC8

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NJb4Fu

Comment: @HolyBlackCat make sure to throw -O3 to compiler args - otherwise analyzer doesn't do much.

Comment: @SergeyA Huh, I see. OP, make sure to mention all your flags next time.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat, done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is no strict aliasing rule violation in the provided code. It looks like a bug in gcc.

You can submit a bugreport to gcc (I was not able to find anything already there related to the snippet provided), however, judging by life and times of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41874 I would not expect immediate fix.